# Django bootstrap-pagination work with inherited templates?

Tags: django, pagination

Does "bootstrap-pagination" in Django work with inherited template files? I have a situation like the following. I have a template file like so:

```
*{% extends "shared/table.html" %}*
*... some html stuff ...
....end of file ...*
```

Then I have the table.html like so:

```
*{% extends "shared/tablepage.html" %}
{% load bootstrap_pagination %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>*
*...some html table here...*
*{% bootstrap_paginate pagination_query range=10 show_prev_next="false" show_first_last="true" %}*
```

end of file.

I am doing something wrong here. But what is that? I can see the list of page links in the page. But all pages contain all the records. The views file is absolutely "traditional". It contains the necessary code and that code works with template files that are not inherited (or use inheritance).